# Embed and reference an EXE in c#

Tags: c#, embed, exe

I am looking to create and call a reference to a compiled .net exe file in a c# program and spawn it from my C# while outputting a single .exe.

Is this possible or am I wasting my time?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you break it down into the different steps?

Comment: You are trying to invoke/refer a *.exe,from your C# program and then get the output as single *.exe. Is it what you are trying to say ?

Comment: Yes Pawan, trying to wrap it and then create a licensing code around it.

Comment: rarely u see questions this clear, concise and to the point on SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is what you need, but you can reference any dotnet exe just as you would reference a dll. The target platform (x86, x64) must be the same if set in the referenced exe.

Comment: Tha'ts what I am doing, then calling the object.initiateComponent() and run() but I am not seeing it show up.  Just my c# window form.

Comment: @Michael: Probably it is not a good idea to "run" your component, since this could start a second message loop (depending on how this component works). Instead you should open its main form directly: var frm = new component.MainForm();
frm.Show();

Comment: I have this much

 Assembly asmSys = Assembly.LoadFrom("demo.exe");
 Type t = asmSys.GetType("SysCompiled.Application");
 SysCompiled.Application sys = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as SysCompiled.Application;

But when I call sys.InitializeComponent(); it says file not found or dependency.  Demo.exe is a self contained .net exe assembly.  Not sure what is missing.

Comment: I successfully byte loaded the exe as an embedded resource.  But when I Assembly.EntryPoint.Invoke it runs but doesn't launch the app, I believe it is being confused on what the actual entry point is due to the smart assembly obfuscation & encryption. 
Yet if i use AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly("filename") it works, I tried replacing that with AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(assembly.FullName) but it can't find it.  I feel like I am very close but I can't quite get it to work since this assembly is encrypted.

Comment: If you have a reference to the exe, you will not have to load the assembly explicitly. It is already loaded and you can use the classes defined in the exe. With a reference, it makes no sense to start the exe! If you really want to run it, then use the approach described by Lirik.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx):

```
Process myProc;

// Start the process.
myProc = Process.Start("C:\path\to\yourexecutable.exe");

//The process does something.
//...

// Stop the process.
myProc.CloseMainWindow();
```

However, I'm not following on the "embed" part. What are you trying to embed? What does "outputting a single .exe" mean?

Answer (score 0):

This might of some interest to you :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx