# Is it right to add c# windows exe as reference in another c# winform?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have c# winform application. and I am able to add this exe as reference in another winform application.

It is working great like dll type.

As of now, I don't see any issues. Is there any issues I need to look into in this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embed and reference an EXE in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068013/embed-and-reference-an-exe-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Your bin folder is going to contain both .exe files, which is rather odd for the user. Better do things the right way, creating a class library for all shared code and reference it in both exes.

Comment: Technically it might work ok. But you should check why you are doing it. If there is something you want to share between both executables, you should build a shared library, also known as a dll.

Comment: It's a kind of odd thing to do, you would need to distribute this exe with your app as if it were a dll. Better to extract the relevant code into a new DLL and reference that DLL from both programs.

Comment: It is a bit unusual but I don't see any problem in that as long as the two programs are related in some way. I mean, is the user  supposed to have both programs on its PC? What happen if the user starts the program that act as DLL by itself? Is the resulting behavior acceptable or not?

Comment: @Steve, I would like to inject few UI features in to existing exe without making changes. If there are any issues in the extended application, then user can use the existing exe. Once everything stabilized, have plan to make exe to dll.

Comment: @HighCore: Not if the the assembly is embedded.  This is doable via [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx), but ILMerge's author recommends [hooking on `AssemblyResolve`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx) instead.

Comment: @Brian that's right, however it still feels like an "ugly" solution in the sense that it requires more steps for something that should be resolved by creating a shared `dll` instead...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is fine.  The CLR doesn't actually care at all about the filename extension, nor does the IDE when you add a reference.

All that the CLR knows is the *display name* of an assembly.  In other words, when it is asked to look for an assembly then it goes by the full name first.  For example:

```
    ClassLibrary1, Version=1.2.3.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

It first looks in the GAC for an *exact* match on the display name (ClassLibrary1), version and token.  Failing that, it then goes looking for a file in the probing path of your program.  Just "ClassLibrary1".  Note that no filename extension is specified at all.  It will first attempt to find "ClassLibrary1.EXE".  Failing that, it next tries to find "ClassLibrary1.DLL'.  No further extensions are tried.  You can see this being done with Fuslogvw.exe btw.

Note how there's a nasty problem associated with this approach, a DLL cannot have the same filename as an EXE.  The CLR will load the EXE when it is asked to resolve the DLL assembly.  That's a kaboom of course.  A problem that is discovered [the hard way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14965526/17034).  That it looks for an EXE first instead of last is, well, odd.

So, nothing to fret about.  Just renaming the .exe to a .dll is fine as well.

Comment: Fascinating about the mixed-mode assembly problem.  Do you have a reference for that?